# Capturing output of perl script called through pipe from another perl script

Tags: perl

Here is the code snippet of main script. The main script is calling populate_details script through pipe. Sending 2 arrays inv1 and inv2 as input.

```
 *my $fh = FileHandle->new('| ./populate_details') 
 print $fh Data::Dumper->Dump([\@inv1], [qw(inv1)]);
 print $fh Data::Dumper->Dump([\@inv2], [qw(inv2)]);*
```

The question is , how to capture the return code and return value from populate_details script ? For example, the populate_details script is sending as hash of return values.

Could you Please help ?

Comment: Tip: No point in using FileHandle. You can use `open(my $fh, '| ./populate_details')`

Comment: For sending hashes between processes you could use JSON, see for example [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS)

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please give me an example plz , on how to get the hash from the child script ?

Comment: Scripts do not return things. Check out [perldoc perlmod](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod#Perl-Modules) for how to set up Perl code so it can be called from other Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the exit status, [`close` the filehandle and check `$?`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#close)

> If the filehandle came from a piped open, `close` returns false if one of the other syscalls involved fails or if its program exits with non-zero status. If the only problem was that the program exited non-zero, `$!` will be set to 0. Closing a pipe also waits for the process executing on the pipe to exit--in case you wish to look at the output of the pipe afterwards--**and implicitly puts the exit status value of that command into `$?` and `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`**.

Comment: Thanks !! If i need to capture the return hash sent by the child script, how to capture it ?

Comment: Check out [`IPC::Open2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open2#DESCRIPTION)